# Java Varargs: find index of a number in array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, variadic-functions

I am trying to find an index of a number in array. I am using varargs method.
My task was to find minimum of numbers and then find his position.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(minimum(2.4, 4.5, -11.3, 3.9, -7.2, -12.1, 14.8));
    }
    public static double minimum(double... n) {
        int k = 0;
        double min = n[k];

        for (double i : n) {
            k++;
            if (i < min) {
                min = i;
            }
            if (min == n[k - 1]) {
                System.out.println("minimum number index is " + (k - 1));
            }
        }
        return min;
```

Outcome is this

```
index of minimum: 0
index of minimum: 2
index of minimum: 5
-12.1
```

When i put System.out.print outside of for loop printing last value for k. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps. Just got to keep the min index in a variable just like storing min value.

```
public static double minimum(double... n) {
    int k = 0;
    double min = n[k];
    minIndex = k;

    for (double i : n) {
        k++;
        if (i < min) {
            min = i;
            minIndex = k-1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("minimum number index is " + (minIndex));
    return min;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This solved the issue. All the best.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there !

As you correctly recognized, your variable `k` holds the `index + 1` of the double you are looking at in your for loop.

If you want to keep the index of the smallest value in the array, you need to do the same thing you did with variable `min`. You need an additional variable which you initialize outside the loop. When you find a new "smaller value" in the array, you store the `k-1` in this variable.

When you exit the for loop, that variable will hold the index of the smallest value in the array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped. All the best.